# What if I am called for jury service while away from home for extended periods (UK)?

Tags: united-kingdom, jury

I live in the UK, and I may be away from home for over 6 months. During this time I will still be in the UK, but will not have a postal address.

What happens if I am called for jury service while I am unable to receive the letter? Will I be fined for not responding?

Comment: Is jury duty your *only* concern? There could be other official mail you're missing, or invoices for that matter.

Comment: Related: [Is there a legal requirement in the UK to receive physical post?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/16452/is-there-a-legal-requirement-in-the-uk-to-receive-physical-post)

Comment: I'd guess (though I can't verify) that a court would, at the least, expect you to take reasonable measures to ensure that your mail gets to you.  That's what people normally do when they travel: [redirection](https://www.royalmail.com/personal/receiving-mail/redirection), asking a friend or neighbor to collect and forward it, etc.  If you don't have a street address to forward to, you can use [poste restante](https://www.postoffice.co.uk/mail/poste-restante).  Do you have some really exceptional situation where nothing like this would be reasonable?

Comment: If you aren't getting mail anywhere, how would they give you notice that you have to serve? Also, in such a long absence, I'd wonder if your "home" continues to be your place of residence for purposes of eligibility for jury service in the court where you "home" is located.